# Background processing in Django without Celery

Tags: python, ajax, django, asynchronous, django-celery

I have a very small part of a Django site that keeps the state of a moderated chat session between two users. Basically, the first user speaks for 3 minutes (and no one else can), then the second user speaks, then a 30 second pause, and the process is repeated one more time. I'm currently using the database and a "RoomState" model to manage the current state of the room (who can speak, etc). State transitions are affected by the client sending a "ping" AJAX POST message every 10 seconds to one of my views, which checks if it's time to change state.

This works, but definitely feels hacky. I was wondering if there was something more lightweight than django-celery + rabbitmq to manage short lived background tasks on a timer. I realize that the nature of the web/Django is stateless, but I just wanted to see if anyone had a simple suggestion to manage the state transitions in a more reliable way.

Comment: If rabbitmq is too heavyweight, consider using the Redis backend instead.

Comment: Please consider updating the selected answer.

Comment: I totally agree with OP everytime we need to upgrade either Django or Celery one of the two breaks. We're on scanning the web for headache number 10 now. Celery has 496 outstanding issues on git hub and a whopping 37 pull requests that are never going to be pulled in. All we ever was reliable scheduled tasks which celery is not. The devs waste their time integrating another backend no one gives a sh*** about.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Author of django-utils here, I'd suggest trying out my newer project [Huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey) -- has richer feature set, better docs, more stable and works with any python framework (including django).  [Docs](https://github.com/coleifer/huey).

Answer (score 7):

I know only one alternative to *Celery* that is more lightweight: [Queue in django-utils](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/a-lightweight-task-queue-for-django/).

Another way is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module directly but you'll probably have to solve some problems that are already solved in *Celery* and *django-utils*.

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/coleifer/huey instead i'm no longer maintaining django-utils

Comment: You probably want to look at [Django Q](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/) which is django specific and the stated goals of the author are exactly what you are asking for. FYI: I have no affiliation and do not know the author.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend [django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks). I've used it in several projects and it does really well as a simple task runner. It was also recommended in [*Two-Scoops of Django*](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8).

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to have become abandonware at some point much like its predecessor